# Read multi-part form data without saving locally in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

To read multi-part form data, .NET has a MultipartFormDataStreamProvider class. To work with the class, a temporary folder is required. This leaves some sort of residue. Is there anyway I can work with an in-memory stream?

Comment: You should be able to read from the content stream yourself into a memory stream

Comment: Thanks Allan. The other class provides some useful properties. I may have to check the now open-source .net framework to write similar code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET has a [MultipartMemoryStreamProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.multipartmemorystreamprovider(v=vs.118).aspx) class. The class does not require a temporary folder. At the same time, a lot more code is required to parse the stream data and extract the contents. If this behaviour is required, subclass MultipartMemoryStreamProvider and add additional methods to mimic MultipartFormDataStreamProvider class.